# SpringXD Kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar and NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException And Enum

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-xd, kryo

I just noticed that we are facing Kryo Issues with a new payload in one of our new Streams in Spring XD (We are planning to jump to Spring Cloud Data Flow soon, so suggestion based on it, might no be applicable right now :(

This is part of the log I saw:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/xxx/yyy/MyEnumClassEnum;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:215) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:182) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:155) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.yyy.MyEnumClassEnum
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

I also noticed, it is happening just with Enum classes. Some fields in that Pojo Object are enum, and I saw it is just failing there.

**Edit 1:**
I have checked the jar file related to my SpringXD module. Inside the jar I found the artifact jar, I opened it and the class is inside. So this is not a problem related to a not existing class inside the jar.

I might share the POJO structure as it is autogenerated. Maybe the way the Enum it is being serialized and after that used my be the root issue.

How should I deal with this issue knowing that just the Enum field is the one triggering the ClassNotFound NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: This simply means that `com.xxx.yyy.MyEnumClassEnum` is not visible to the classloader. Have you tried to look at the actual shaded JAR (inside) and see if it was properly generated and that the classes are there?

Comment: Yes. I had already opened the jar and it has the class inside. Basically the SpringXD custom module has the jar and the class inside, but something happen it is not found. Funny thing is now I explicitly put the jar that contains the class under the xd/lib folder and it solved the problem. But now I'm getting the same error for another Enum field inside of the same pojo, but class related to that Enum is also inside the jar. I don't want to move that jar that contains that Enum class to the xd/folder since it would be a big mess and NO NO for the entire project where we are working on.